# 502 Bad Gateway error on nginx - Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I had a Django app running alright on Ubuntu server with nginx and gunicorn. All was well until I tried to kill gunicorn, change some settings in settings.py and tried to restart nginx and gunicorn. Gunicorn runs without any issue but I get `502 Bad Gateway` and my error log from nginx looks like this:

```
2015/07/07 09:18:23 [error] 19905#0: *14 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) 
while connecting to upstream, client: 101.212.66.163, server: domainname.com, 
request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://domainip:8001/", host: "www.domainname.com"
```

What's wrong here? Sorry I'm pretty new to nginx and gunicorn both.

**EDIT** 
: I wiped out everything in hope of resetting everything again but I am getting exact same error

My conf for application in /etc/nginx/sites-available/appname looks like this:

```
server {
        server_name domainname.com;

        access_log off;

        location /static/ {
            alias /opt/myenv/static/;
        }

        location /media/ {
            alias /opt/myenv/media/;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://domain_ip:8001;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM N$
        }
```

Comment: check your settings.py for syntax error or typo errors. This usually happens when database is in locked state or its crashed(very rare)

Comment: @AjayGupta Is there a way to check django error log? I don't think settings.py has any error, still I would want to confirm.

Comment: yes you can check for logs in nginx directory. I guess the logs would be present in /var/log/nginx/error/

Comment: @AjayGupta I see errors.log and access.log in /var/log/nginx folder. Have posted snippet of error in question.

Comment: lets see your settings changes and your nginx configuration

Comment: @AjayGupta Posting them with an edit. Give me a moment.

Comment: @Maxsteel what does your Gunicorn error log say? If you're using upstart look at `/var/log/upstart/gunicorn.log`